# Is there any API which can provide information on different animal species

Tags: api

I am working on a project (not a programming project) where we require a lot of information about different species such as average weight, lifespan, height, population numbers, endangered status etc.

I have been looking for an API to provide this information so that I don't have to manually search for it for over 100 species and I can't find anything that provides the information.

The best I have found so far is an API provided by the IUCN Red list, but this doesn't have all the information required (e.g. no lifespan data or weight)

Are there any APIs available which will provide this information?

Comment: wikidata.org provides query-based access to data in wikipedia.org and that may be your best bet. https://biodiversitymapping.org/wordpress/index.php/home/ may also be helpful but is limited

Comment: Thanks @Barry, that helped. I was directed to Open Data from this question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/71487/36954 where the same was suggested after I posted here